# Is there a more dynamic way to sanitize ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, request, sql-injection

i have a from, 2 of the fields are the following

```
<select name="sortfield">
    <option value="name" selected="selected">Name</option>
    <option value="price">Price</option>
    <option value="id">ID Code</option>
</select>
<select name="sortdir">
    <option value="asc" selected="selected">Ascending</option>
    <option value="desc">Descending</option>
</select>
```

this are obtained via `$_REQUEST[]` on the next page which is then added to the query to determin how the results of a query are sorted, the quick, dirty, un-sanitized way is this

```
$query .= "ORDER BY ".$_REQUEST['sortfield']." ".$_REQUEST['sortdir'];
```

obviously this can be a problem with sql injection, one way i can fix this is to change the values and have a switch case when making the query to swap out the values, something like this

```
switch($_REQUEST['sortfield'])
{
    case '5524879':
        $query .= "ORDER BY name";
        break;
    case '4587532':
        $query .= "ORDER BY price";
        break;
    default:
        $query .= "ORDER BY id";
}
```

while this can help prevent sql injection it's not very dynamic since page will have to be changed every time if the query/table structure changes, i am wondering if there is a more dynamic way to sanitize the strings rather than having to use a `switch ... case`

Comment: Validate the values with a white list.

Comment: @Gumbo he *does* that if you didn't notice

Comment: @SajunaFernando because **NO STRINGS** involved here?

Comment: @sskoko and all who upvoted: to let you know, this function is useless here.

Answer (score 1):

A more dynamic way would be to create an array of table fields with [show fields](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html), and use that as a white list when checking the value of of your `sortfield`

```
if ( !in_array( $_REQUEST['sortfield'], $table_fields ) ) {
    // error
}
```

I also recommend not using $_REQUEST at all. You should know where your variables are coming from.

> The variables in $_REQUEST are provided to the script via the GET,
>   POST, and COOKIE input mechanisms and therefore could be modified by
>   the remote user and cannot be trusted. The presence and order of
>   variables listed in this array is defined according to the PHP
>   variables_order configuration directive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for the order by clause you can only format dynamical identifier, without checking it against a whitelist.

```
if (!empty($_GET['sortfield']))
{
    $query .= "ORDER BY `".str_replace("`","``",$_GET['sortfield'])."`";
} else {
    $query .= "ORDER BY id";
}
```

Note that it will protect you from injection but won't save from SQL syntax error - so, it's better to verify the field name anyway.

Also, there could be no `id` field in the table, and thus this code is not very dynamic too. So, it's better to stick to a whitelist anyway. After all, it is not *that* hard. Sometimes manual amendments are better then automated ones.